# What is the response code when Truspilot refresh token expires?

Tags: trustpilot

I am using Trustpilot API and I need to handle a scenario when refresh token expires. I did not find the response in API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If the API indicates that your token is expired, the scenario is covered.  How you handle this is the scope of you application and not the API.